# How do I refer to an object of an object?

Tags: java, oop

A class circle creates and uses an class secant to calculate its diameter. Now a GUI class needs to get a field (number of iterations used by the numerical method called "secant" to make the calculation) from a particular secant object used by a particular circle object. How should I perform such a reference?

Number of iterations is not a property of a circle. Should I force it to become that anyway?

Comment: If the reference fields in question are public it's `circle.secant.iterations`.  If they're not public you need accessor methods.

Comment: please, add some code examples to your question.

Comment: Is `secant` a ***method*** or an ***object***?  You state both, which is of course possible, but pretty confusing...

Comment: Secant is an object. In math terminology it is a "numerical method", and i see now how that is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info you provided - You just need to provide a getter/accessor method in your secant for iterations. So you can do-

```
circle.secant.getIterations();
```

If you make the iterations property public-

```
circle.secant.iterations;
```

If you have a getter for secant as well, then-

```
circle.getSecant().getIterations();
```

Comment: But secant is not a method or field in circle, it is a third class. The GUI class wants to reach the specific secant object which a certain circle object has used. Secant has fields about what it has doen, like number of iterations. The circle has fields for what it is, like its diameter. The GUI object needs to pair the two and collect information from both.

Comment: To reach secant, the gui needs to reach the circle. Your circle is holding a secant instance as you said the circle uses the secant. So, in gui class, you should be able to first get/point to the circle and then get the secant instance of the circle, and finally the iterations off the secant instance. Circle -> Secant -> getIterations().

Comment: Okay, so the circle should have a field which links it to the secant object it has used. Maybe ideally a factory class should be used to keep track of how the circle was instantiated? So that the circle could have fields only about its own circular properties.

Comment: @LocalFluff Your circle should have an instance member that holds a reference to a secant object. Something like this:  public class Circle { public Secant secant; public Circle(){this.secant = new Secant();}}

Comment: Thanx, I just had problems making it public.